# Avoid clicking on google maps in phonegap

Tags: google-maps, cordova, cordova-3

I have integrated google maps in phonegap application.
I want to avoid any kind of clicking of links on google maps in my phonegap application.
When i zoom in map and clicks any link in google maps, then another pages gets opened. and i am unable to return to my application.
Is it possible to avoid this clicking functionality inside maps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help ?

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, true);
```